# Can I center and middle a figure in html xaringan R

Tags: css, xaringan

I notice that you can center and middle the layout of a slide using `class: center, middle` in xaringan slides, but that changes the title and layout of the entire slide. You can also center the image by:

```
.center[
![]('foo.svg')
]
```

But I wonder if I can center the plot and also make it at middle of the slide without changing the layout of the entire page in xaringan?

Thanks!

Comment: I quickly checked `.center.middle[]` but it's not working. but I think it's not hard to tackle. This question indicates that our wiki needs to improve! https://github.com/yihui/xaringan

Comment: Yeah `middle` works only for remark slide as a whole. I have a work around creating a class `vmiddle` for this which I'll post soon.

Comment: Oops I realised my work around only works on my theme because of the way I define the columns. I guess the easiest way to adjust is to include lots of `<br>` for now

Comment: @Emi Thanks for your response. Could you post an answer with replicable codes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:
define a `.center2` class at the beginning of your rmd or in a separate CSS file:

```
<style>

.center2 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

</style>
```

Then insert the image, wrap it with `.center2[]` :

````
.center2[
```{r echo = FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("path/to/image")
```
]
````

Comment: Thank you for your response. From my understanding, .fig.align = 'center' can horizontally center the figure in Rmarkdown, but can I center the figure both vertically and horizontally, .i.e. put the figure at the very middle of the slide. I think this is usefully when we need to put the figure in the slide.

Comment: Ahh, I see. so we have to deal with CSS styles here. I edited my answer, please have a try.